# Getting optional not unwrapped error when it is unwrapped

Tags: core-data, swift2

I have Car entity and Price entity which has one-to-many relationship(Each car has the lowest price and the highest price for a given year. Price entity keeps track of year and the lowest/highest price for that year). I'm fetching car data from coredata. Since price is stored as NSSet in Car class, I'm iterating through each price and stored them in 2D array as follows :

```
var prices = [[Double]]()

// This line of code is made to return only one car by predicate
let cars = try moc.executeFetchRequest(carData) as! [Car]

for c in cars {
    for p in c.price! {
        prices[p.id!.intValue][0] = p.lowest
        prices[p.id!.intValue][1] = p.highest                    
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use id value of the price entity as an array index, but I'm getting "Value of optional type NSNumber not unwrapped" error. As you can see, it is already unwrapped. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you try using if let id = p.id as NSNumber ?

Comment: Please explain question in detail?